create a saved search formula to compute days rendered based on system notes
I wanted to compute for days rendered on a project status, for example project status "in que" on 3/1/2024 and entered "sent to sales" on 3/4/2024, expected output should be 3 days on the days rendered.
Here is my current formula in the saved search but its showing invalid expression on the saved search results:
=CASE WHEN{ systemnotes.newvalue
    ARRAYROWSTOP)
ARRAYSTOP) = 'Proposal - Sent to Sales' THEN TO_DATE(
{ systemnotes.date
        ARRAYROWSTOP)
    ARRAYSTOP)
)  ELSE IF{ systemnotes.newvalue
    ARRAYROWSTOP)
ARRAYSTOP) = 'Proposal - In Queue'  THEN TO_DATE(
{ systemnotes.date
        ARRAYROWSTOP)
    ARRAYSTOP)
) *- 1  ELSE 0  END


Would this simplified attempt work? =CASE WHEN {systemnotes.newvalue ARRAYROWSTOP ARRAYSTOP} = 'Proposal - Sent to Sales' THEN TO_DATE({systemnotes.date ARRAYROWSTOP ARRAYSTOP}) - TO_DATE({systemnotes.date ARRAYROWSTOP+1 ARRAYSTOP}) ELSE 0 END

CASE WHEN {systemnotes.newvalue}= 'Proposal - Sent to Sales'
THEN TO_DATE({systemnotes.date})
ELSEIF {systemnotes.newvalue}= 'Proposal - In Queue'
THEN TO_DATE({systemnotes.date})*-1
ELSE 0
END
This was the formula that im currently using but im encountering invalid expression
